# Normal/Gaussian Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

The time spent waiting for a bus is normally distributed with a mean equal to 10 minutes and a standard deviation equal to 10 minutes.
Find the probability of waiting less than 12 minutes.

Need help figuring this one out. Unsure how to start this question.

Comment: So you know that $T \sim N(10,10^2)$ and you are finding the probability that $T<12$. That's all the information you needed already. You can just use a calculator to find the probability. I'm not sure where you get stuck...

Comment: evidently the probability of waiting -1 minute is greater than 0.

Comment: It is absurd to use that as the model of time spent waiting for a bus, since it leads to a probability of around $1/6$ that the waiting time is negative.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, what do you expect as an outcome? $\mathbb{P}(T<12)$ will be bigger than 0.5 because the normal distribution is symmetric around $\mu$ and $12>10$.

The second thing you need to do is make your stochastic (say T) standard normal. We know that $T\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ so in general: $Z=\frac{T-\mu}{\sigma} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, so in our case: $Z=\frac{T-10}{10}$ is standard normal. Now the question is reduced to this: $$\mathbb{P}(Z<0.2), \ Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

Now you take the standard normal table in front of you and look for $z=0.2$. You will find the value $0.5793$ and this is your probability (>0.5 as expected).